# wxDev-C++ - HtmlHelp undeclared

Tags: c++, c

In my `C` program's menu I have a Help section.

When pressed, it should open a help file.

I used `Helpinator Professional` to make a simple help file.

Now, pre-history:

I tried using the WinHelp() method by including `<winuser.h>`. It opened the file, but it gave me an error, saying that the file is not a Windows Help file or is corrupted. Then I read that WinHelp() is outdated and I should use HtmlHelp() instead by including `<htmlhelp.h>`. I included it by writing the full path to it, because wxDev-C++'s directories in compiler settings are not included normally and I don't exactly know how it checks the directories.

I included  in my resources.h file.
Code in switch statement:

```
case ID_Help:
HtmlHelp(hwnd, "file location", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, 0);
break;
```

This gives me an error, saying that it is undeclared. Then, I declared `HWMD help;` before the switch statement and changed code to:

```
case ID_Help:
help = HtmlHelp(hwnd, "file location", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, 0);
break;
```

And it still tells me that it is undeclared.

What should I do? I'm stuck. I also encountered other problems on the way, some of them mentioned above, but nevermind them for now.

Source code:

```
#include "resources.h"


/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char window_class[] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = window_class;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_HAND);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE (ID_Menu);                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BACKGROUND + 2);

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           window_class,         /* Classname */
           "Slacker Tracker v0.1",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           600,                 /* The programs width */
           600,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    MessageBox(NULL, "Message box #1 at your service.", "MESSAGE BOX #1", 0);

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPCTSTR name = "D:\\winapi\\1\\help.chm";
    HANDLE file;
    int size;
    char buffer[100];
    wchar_t error[256];
    HWND help;
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
                switch(LOWORD(wParam))
                    {
                        case ID_File_Exit:
                            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                            break;
                        case ID_NewMsgBox:
                            MessageBox(NULL, "Message box #3 at your service", "MESSAGE BOX #3", 0);
                            break;
                        case ID_Help:
                            //WinHelp(hwnd, "D:\\winapi\\1\\help.chm", HELP_INDEX, 0);
                            help = HtmlHelp(hwnd, "D:\\winapi\\1\\help.chm", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, 0);
                            break;
                        case ID_FSize:
                            file = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
                            if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
                                FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, GetLastError(),
                                               MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), error, 255, NULL);
                                MessageBoxW(NULL, error, (LPCWSTR)L"file", 0);
                            }
                            else{
                                size = GetFileSize(file, NULL);
                                itoa(size, buffer, 10);
                                MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "File Size", MB_OK);
                            }
                            CloseHandle(file);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Message box #2 at your service", "MESSAGE BOX #2", 0);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile log:

```
main.c: In function 'WindowProcedure':
main.c:99:36: error: 'HtmlHelp' undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:99:36: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: Could you put a section of the actual source?  And what are the actual error messages you are seeing?

Comment: @RichardChambers

Updated OP.

Comment: See [Including HTML Help Files in an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733984(v=vs.60).aspx) and you do need to `#include <htmlhelp.h>` which contains the necessary declarations and definitions needed.  You will also need to make sure that `Htmlhelp.lib` is specified as a library to link against.  You may want to create a sample Win32 Project and specify Context Sensitive help in the wizard to create an example to work with.

Comment: @RichardChambers

The .lib and .h files of HtmlHelp are in the HTML Help Workshop folder, so in my compiler options I linked those folders; in my resources.h file I included the htmlhelp.h file separately by writing it's full path.

Now when compiling I get an error, saying:

`[Linker Error] undefined reference to `HtmlHelpA@16'`
`ld returned 1 exit status`
`D:\winapi\1\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Output/MingW/Project1.exe] Error 1`  


So is the library file not being found?

Comment: The error message does indicate that it could not find the HtmlHelp() function.  However the error message indicate HtmlHelpA which I believe is the non-UNICODE version of the HtmlHelp() function.  In Windows to provide compatibility with Windows 95/98 there were the non-UNICODE Windows API which had a letter A appended to the end of the function name and a set of Preprocessor macros decide whether to use the old non-Unicode Windows API or the newer UNICODE Windows API first available with Windows NT and later.  Are you using Visual Studio?  You may need to include UNICODE in your settings.

Comment: @RichardChambers 
Apparently it works without the A or W.
I found the solution.

In the Compiler Options there is a box that says "Add these commands to the linker command line".
All I had to do was write '-lhtmlhelp' in there and it compiled without any problems.

Problem solved, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line to your .cpp file.

```
#include "htmlhelp.h"
```

Then you need to assign the event to call help. (this is where I think it is stating that it is undefined)

```
void CTestHelpDlg::OnHelp() 
{
  HtmlHelp(this->m_hWnd, "HelpSample.chm", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, NULL);
}
```

Further documentation and the tutorial I used for learning this is here

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/help/html/article.php/c6503/Starting-Out-with-HtmlHelp.htm